# .apply throwing exception when applied with classList.remove

Tags: javascript, dom, domtokenlist

I was trying something and faced this issue. When you try to do `element.classList.remove.apply`, it throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

You can test it using following snippet.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.test');
var classesToRemove = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
div.classList.remove.apply(div, classesToRemove);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.test1 {
  color: blue
}

.test2 {
  background: gray;
}

.test3 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='test test1 test2 test3'>Test</div>
```

---

**Note:** I'm aware that I can solve this using spread operator(`...`), but I'm more interested in understanding why this fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely use Function.prototype.apply here too, however correct context for invocation is `div.classList` object, not HTMLElement `div` itself.

Try this:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.test');
var classesToRemove = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
div.classList.remove.apply(div.classList, classesToRemove);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.test1 {
  color: blue
}

.test2 {
  background: gray;
}

.test3 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='test test1 test2 test3'>Test</div>
```

Comment: My bad! I missed this. I guess this makes the question a typographical mistake. If you can remove the answer, I'll remove the post

Comment: In that case, I'll keep it. I guess this question falls in that grey zone. Hence considered it as typo.